# creating a file downloading script with checksum verification

Tags: bash, curl, shell, checksum, backticks

I want to create a shellscript that reads files from a .diz file, where information about various source files are stored, that are needed to compile a certain piece of software (imagemagick in this case). i am using Mac OSX Leopard 10.5 for this examples.

Basically i want to have an easy way to maintain these .diz files that hold the information for up-to-date source packages. i would just need to update these .diz files with urls, version information and file checksums.

Example line:

```
libpng:1.2.42:libpng-1.2.42.tar.bz2?use_mirror=biznetnetworks:http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/00-libpng-stable/1.2.42/libpng-1.2.42.tar.bz2?use_mirror=biznetnetworks:9a5cbe9798927fdf528f3186a8840ebe
```

script part:

```
while IFS=: read app version file url md5
do 
  echo "Downloading $app Version: $version"
  curl -L -v -O $url 2>> logfile.txt
  $calculated_md5=`/sbin/md5 $file | /usr/bin/cut -f 2 -d "="`
  echo $calculated_md5    
done < "files.diz"
```

Actually I have more than just one question concerning this.

1. how to calculate and compare the checksums the best? i wanted to store md5 checksums in the .diz file and compare it with string comparison with "cut"ting out the string
2. is there a way to tell curl another filename to save to? (in my case the filename gets ugly libpng-1.2.42.tar.bz2?use_mirror=biznetnetworks)
3. i seem to have issues with the backticks that should direct the output of the piped md5 and cut into the variable $calculated_md5. is the syntax wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while IFS=: read app version file url md5
do
  echo "Downloading $app Version: $version"
  #use -o for output file. define $outputfile yourself
  curl -L -v  $url -o $outputfile 2>> logfile.txt
  # use $(..) instead of backticks.
  calculated_md5=$(/sbin/md5 "$file" | /usr/bin/cut -f 2 -d "=")
  # compare md5
  case "$calculated_md5" in
    "$md5" )
      echo "md5 ok"
      echo "do something else here";;
  esac
done < "files.diz"
```

Comment: great! thanks for the fast answer! except the typo on line 11 (2 ";" chars) everything seems to work! i also had to change the delimiter to ";" since ":" is of course also in "http:". thanks a lot!

Comment: that 2 ";" chars in case/esac is valid.

Comment: the only strange thing is, that the curl -o switch seems not to work AT ALL! see it for yourself: curl -L -v -O http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/00-libpng-stable/1.2.42/libpng-1.2.42.tar.bz2?use_mirror=biznetnetworks -o libpng.tar.bz2 - any ideas?

Comment: strangely, bash would not let me run the script with the 2 ";" characters: syntax error near unexpected token `"do something else here"' - are you sure it is correct?

Comment: because you have -O switch. remove it and should be fine. check the man page to see what -O switch does.

Comment: thanks! here is the right syntax for the case statement:

  case "$calculated_md5" in
    " $md5")
      echo "md5 ok"
 ;;
 *)
 echo "do something else here"
  esac

Comment: the ";;" must be at the last statement. ie ... echo "do something else here" ;; esac

Comment: strange... i put my code on a pastie for you to see how it works for me: http://pastie.org/783216

Comment: yes, it should work. what i meant is , if you have multiple statements in each  case condition  eg condition) , then you must use ;; before the next condition.

Answer (score 9):

The following is a practical one-liner:

```
curl -s -L <url> | tee <destination-file> |
sha256sum -c <(echo "a748a107dd0c6146e7f8a40f9d0fde29e19b3e8234d2de7e522a1fea15048e70  -") ||
rm -f <destination-file>
```

wrapping it up in a function taking 3 arguments:
- the url
- the destination
- the sha256

```
download() {
   curl -s -L $1 | tee $2 | sha256sum -c <(echo "$3  -") || rm -f $2
}
```

Comment: This saved my day! Neat use of `tee` and process substitution there.

Answer (score 0):

My `curl` has a `-o` (`--output`) option to specify an output file.  There's also a problem with your assignment to `$calculated_md5`.  It shouldn't have the dollar sign at the front when you assign to it.  I don't have `/sbin/md5` here so I can't comment on that.  What I do have is `md5sum`.  If you have it too, you might consider it as an alternative.  In particular, it has a `--check` option that works from a file listing of md5sums that might be handy for your situation.  HTH.

Comment: thanks for the answer; osx does not have md5sum but md5 (which is from the openssl package)

Comment: furthermore, the -o switch seems not to work on osx (curl 7.16.3) - see my comment above.